# How to generate html report using ant with jmeter

Tags: ant, jmeter

I am tring to generate the html report using ant for that I have performed below steps In my machine java  and jmeter is already installed. I performed below steps

- Download Apache Ant and unzip it. Copy the complete unzipped folder to 
  C:\apache-ant-1.9.11-bin
- Open Jmeter folder and then open Extras folder shown inside Jmeter forlder : 
  C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras
- Copied the Extras folder and pasted it to C:\apache-ant-1.9.11-bin\apache- 
  ant-1.9.11\bin
- Updated build.xml

  ```
   Djmeter.home=.. - C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0
   <property name="jmeter.home" value="C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0"/>
  ```
- Created Test.jtl file at C:\apache-ant-1.9.11-bin\apache-ant-1.9.11\bin
- Opened the command promt and run below command

  ```
  C:\apache-ant-1.9.11-bin\apache-ant-1.9.11\bin>ant
  ```

It generates belew *Error* message on command promt.

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\tools.jar Buildfile: C:\apache-ant-1.9.11-bin\apache-ant-1.9.11\bin\build.xml
```

As per your suggestion I added the code below still facing the below error.

[image: ErrorGenerated]

here is the path for tool.jar file that I set in above image.

[image: Tools path]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With regards to "tools.jar" message it indicates that your Java installation differs from what Ant expects, probably you didn't select option to install [Public JRE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDJCCEG) during Java setup. So the options are in:

   - Either re-install Java with Public JRE now (and preferably to the location which doesn't contain spaces or national characters in its path)
   - Or ignore the warning, it should not have impact on JMeter
2. Manipulations with copying "extras" folder are not necessary, you can verify that JMeter Ant Task is working by just running `ant` inside "Extras" folder, assuming everything goes well it should generate `Test.html` file there

Also be aware that starting from JMeter 3.0 there is an option to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) with way more detailed information than Ant task provides.

References:

- [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Thanks for your reply